# Html.ActionLink with non-C# friendly htmlAttribute names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[Disqus](http://docs.disqus.com/developers/universal/#comment-count) wants me to add an attribute called `data-disqus-identifier` to my links, but for obvious reasons, `new { @data-disqus-identifier = "article" }` gives me a syntax error.

Any idea what to do in these situations?

Thanks,

Rei

Comment: 2. I wonder if there's less overload hell in 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a `Dictionary<string, object>` with arbitrary string keys.
The syntax will be more verbose: `new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-disqus-identifier", "article" } }`.

You may want to create an extension method or a static method on a static class with a short name that takes a smaller parameter set and returns the dictionary.

Comment: This doesn't work either, it seems to just try to reflect on the Dictionary... `<a comparer="System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[System.String]" count="1" keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]" values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]" >blah</a>`

Comment: `return helper.ActionLink(linkText, "Details", "Articles", null, null, "disqus-thread",
                new
                {
                    year = year,
                    month = month,
                    slug = slug
                },
                new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-disqus-identifier", "article-" + id } }
            );`

Comment: @Rei: Add `new RouteValueDictionary(new { ... })` to the second-to-last parameter.  (You need to match the overload that takes an `IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes`)  You might want to put this into an extension method.

Comment: Ahh there we go. Turns out that the IDictionary overload also requires the route values to be given as a RouteValueDictionary as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In MVC 3, if you use underscore `_` instead of hyphens `-` in your property names then MVC will automatically convert them to hyphens in the resulting HTML. So, something like this should work for you:

```
new { data_disqus_identifier = "article" }
```

Comment: Are you sure? I don't see that in the source.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's an MVC 3 feature.